# AJAX call with CodeIgniter 4 returns 404 errpr

Tags: php, ajax, datatables, codeigniter-4

I have a simple DataTable based page I am building. I want the table to get its data with ajax().

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#tblReport").DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'copyHtml5',
                'excelHtml5',
                'pdfHtml5'
            ],
            ajax: {
                url: '/reports/ajaxopenwolist',
                type: 'POST'
            }
        
        
        }
        );
    });
</script>
```

I have created a method within the controller class. (All other methods in the controller class work fine.) I added a route.

When I load the page, I get a 404 error on the ajax call.

[image]

Now, here's the interesting part. If I copy the URL right out of the error message you see in the image and paste that into a browser, I get the JSON data I expected. So, the URL works but not when called within ajax. (And yes, it is all part of the same domain).

Any thoughts on this. I am honestly at a loss with this one.

Comment: When you request URL in browser it uses `GET` but your ajax request uses `POST`. You have to either use GET in your ajax request or configure your route to accept POST requests.

Comment: BINGO! Now I have to figure out how to configure for POST. Thanks!

Comment: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/routing.html#setting-routing-rules

Comment: You have explicitly mentioned the type as POST in your Datatable AJAX request. But when you load the URL in a browser, it is usually as HTTP GET request, so your route should be set for POST type. Meanwhile if you need the URL to be available for both GET and POST types, you can set that URL for both GET and POST for same controller function or different functions even.